# I want to put my own advertising ID on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, admob

I want to put my own advertising ID. I performed it as a test. Since I'm going to do it for the first time, I don't know how. I would like to know what will change for adUnitId: InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId.

```
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';

class AdmobIslemleri {
  static final String appIDCanli = "ca-app-pub-4588732813144248~4661848947";
  static final String appIDTest = FirebaseAdMob.testAppId;

  static admobInitialize() {
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: appIDTest);
  }

  static final MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
    keywords: <String>['flutterio', 'beautiful apps'],
    contentUrl: 'https://flutter.io',

    childDirected: false,

    // or MobileAdGender.female, MobileAdGender.unknown
    testDevices: <String>[], // Android emulators are considered test devices
  );

  static InterstitialAd buildInterstitialAd() {
    return InterstitialAd(
      // Replace the testAdUnitId with an ad unit id from the AdMob dash.
      // https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads
      // https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads
      adUnitId: InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        print("InterstitialAd event is $event");
      },
    );
  }
}
```